# MySQL ORDER BY TOP 20 and then aggregate all remaining results in one row

Tags: mysql, sql

Assume the following dataset:

```
item    |    amount    |    total_items

beer            5                10
beans           5                15
```

...etc

Imagine that there are 100 items. I want to `SELECT TOP 20 ITEMS ORDER BY AMOUNT DESC`. This will leave 80 items which I want to consolidate/aggregate into a single `item` row named `"Other"` where it's `amount` column will be the `SUM` of `amount`s of those 80 rows, same logic for `total_items`. This means that out of initial 100 rows, only 21 will remain.

Can I do this in a single query? The approach I'm thinking of following is:

1) SELECT TOP 20 and store in a #temp1 table

2) SELECT the rest and store in a #temp2 table

3) SELECT THE SUMS of `amount` and `total_items` from #temp2 so it becomes one row

4) Merge the two results together

Surely there must be a better and more efficient way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
select (case when seqnum <= 20 then item else 'rest' end) as item,
       sum(amount)
from (select it.*, row_number() over (order by amount desc) as seqnum
      from items i
     ) i
group by (case when seqnum <= 20 then item else 'rest' end) 
order by max(seqnum) desc;
```

This assigns a sequential number to each row based on amount (highest amount = 1).  It then aggregates the 20 highest values, putting everything else into the 21st group.

Comment: From my reading of the question, I think you need `<= 20` rather than `= 1`

Comment: thanks @GordonLinoff, I'm trying to wrap my head around windows functions and I'm a bit confused by the syntax of the query. Assuming the table name of my example above is `items`, is `t` in the `FROM` part meant to represent the actual table name?

Comment: Thanks Gordon! I think there's a small typo in the code, `selectit.*` is probably `select i.*` correct? Also, I seem to have more than one instance per `item` in my rows, so ideally I need to be able to group them together. Where should the group by occur in the query?